# Vlookup worksheet function in VBA (runtime error 9)

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm new to VBA and I have the following code for a function :

```
Function checktype(ByVal modele As String)

Dim srchRange As Range
Dim book1 As Workbook

'Set some Workbook variables:
Set book1 = Workbooks("C:\Users\MZ\Desktop\EPI.xlsx")


Set srchRange = book1.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D800")

'This assumes that the Book2 is Open and you are on the desired active worksheet:
checktype = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(modele, srchRange, 4, False)


End Function
```

The aim of this code is to get a certain number from another workbook using Vlookup function and return the value to the function `checktype`.

The problem is that I get a runtime error 9. When I click Debug the following line gets highlighted :

```
Set book1 = Workbooks("C:\Users\MZ\Desktop\EPI.xlsx")
```

Comment: Do you need to open the workbook first with Workbooks.add()?

Comment: `Set book1 = Workbooks("EPI.xlsx")` - assuming the workbook is open, you only need to provide the filename to `Workbooks()`

Answer (score 1):

Either make sure that the workbook is opened in the ***same instance*** of excel and refer it like this:

```
Set book1 = Workbooks("C:\Users\MZ\Desktop\EPI.xlsx")
Set book1 = Workbooks("EPI.xlsx") 'specifying only the name is OK as well
```

or

```
Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MZ\Desktop\EPI.xlsx")
```

---

An example of 2 Excel files in the same instance:

[image]